# Access values of multiple checked boxes

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, forms

I want to access the values of dynamically created check boxes.

```
@ $db = mysql_connect("abc", "abc", "");
                            mysql_select_db("abc");

                            $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM student";
                            $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
                            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs);
                            echo "<i style='color:#fff'> Number of Students = ".$num_rows."</i>";
                            $i=1;
                            while($r = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){

                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td class='promotetabledata'>".$r[7]."</td>";
                            echo "<td class='promotetabledata'>".$r[6]."</td>";
                            echo "<td class='promotetabledata'><input type='checkbox' class='pr'  value='".$r[7]."'/></td>"; /*dynamically created check boxes*/
                            echo "</tr>";
                            $i++;
                }
```

The results are displayed in a `promoteresults div` using AJAX

```
<form id="promotionform" action="promotestudents.php" method="POST">
            <div id="promoteresults">The results will show up here..!!
            </div>


            <div style=" position:relative; margin-top:10px; padding-left:44%;">  
                <button type="submit" class="button black">Promoted</a>
            </div>
    </form>
```

When the promoted button is clicked I want to get the selected records and update their value. To update the records, I need PHP. I can access the selected records in Javascript using

`var selected = document.getElementsByClassName('pr').checked;`

But how do I get the checked records in the HTML form and their values in PHP

The AJAX call with Javascript

```
function getpromotestudents()
{
//alert("hi");

var xmlhttp;
var select1 = document.getElementById('promotefacultyselect1'); 
var facutlyselect = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value;


var select2 = document.getElementById('promotedepartmentselect1'); 
var deptselect = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].value;


var select3 = document.getElementById('promotecourseselect1'); 
var courseselect = select3.options[select3.selectedIndex].value;


var select4 = document.getElementById('promoteyearselect1'); 
var yearselect = select4.options[select4.selectedIndex].value;


var select5 = document.getElementById('promotesemselect1'); 
var semselect = select5.options[select5.selectedIndex].value;


var  the_data = 'faculty='+facutlyselect+' &dept='+deptselect+' &course='+courseselect+' &year='+yearselect+' &sem='+semselect;


if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  /*
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("searchresults").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }*/



  xmlhttp.open("POST", "getpromotestudents.php", true);         // set the request
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");            // adds  a header to tell the PHP script to recognize the data as is sent via POST
  xmlhttp.send(the_data);       // calls the send() method with datas as parameter

  // Check request status
 // If the response is received completely, will be transferred to the HTML tag with tagID
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById("promoteresults").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your ajax call.  Are you using jQuery?

Comment: He wouldn't be bothering with getElementsByClassName if he was using jQuey i think :)

Comment: @vinodadhikary I am using javascript, I have updatedthe question to show you the AJAX part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each of the `checkbox` `name` property like this

```
<input type='checkbox' class='pr'  value='8' name='chk[]'/>
```

Than in the php you can get them as follows

```
<?php
 $chkbox = $_POST['chk'];

 foreach($chkbox as $a => $b){
    echo $chkbox[$a];
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <td class='promotetabledata'><input type='checkbox' name='pr[]'  value='".$r[7]."'/></td>
```

This is the PHP code I finally wrote to access all the checkboxes, and perform the required operations on the selected ones.

```
<?php
    $checkbox = $_POST['pr'];

    foreach($checkbox as $value){

            if(isset($checkbox)){

            echo '<script>alert("'.$value.'")</script>';
            }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set each check box's `name` property to `pr[]`, as in:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' class='pr' name='pr[]' value='".$r[7]."'/>";
```

Then, the first checkbox will be at `$_POST['pr'][0]`, the second at `$_POST['pr'][1]` and so on.

Comment: You can also set the name to `pr[0]`, etc. yourself, in case you need to know the exact checkbox that was checked.

Comment: I read, the name attribute is deprecated in HTML5, and use of id or class is preferred instead.

Comment: Always use both id/name, unless you don't care about ie 6/7/8/9 for the next 10 years to come

Comment: @Akash Gupta : Not for form elements.

Comment: With some luck HTML5 will be official in 2014, it's basically just a release candidate for now, and then we can wait another 10 years for IE9 to die before being able to use it how it is supposed to be used ..or 20 with IE10 :)

Comment: ohkhayzz..I recently ceased using name attribute. Will have to continue again. So the pr[] will automatically create an array of names?

Comment: Was there something wrong with my answer? @Khawer Zeshan had essentially the same thing.